# Allow ModSecurity to pass specific HTML tags?

Tags: html, mod-security, perl

I have a web-server running a Perl site, and I have a WAF (ModSecurity) running. The website has a form. When submitted the request contain HTML tags like so:

```
<br+/>
<div+style="border:none;+border-left:solid+blue+1.5pt;+padding:0cm+0cm+0cm+4.0pt"+type="cite">
<div+style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;+font-size:12pt;+color:#000000">
<div>Ahoy</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>
<div><span+style="color:#333333">TEST Test,</span></div>   
<div><span+style="color:#008000">4950</span></div>
```

How can I pass these tags without triggering ModSecurity and the request getting blocked?

Comment: What ModSecurity rules are you using? Are you using the OWASP ModSecurity CRS? Have you tried something yourself? Have you identified the rule that blocks the request?

Comment: @Sjoerd I'm using OWASP ModSecurity CRS and it blocks the request.

Comment: This is yet another reason why ensuring your inputs are escaped is a much better defense against XSS than trying to reject things that look like HTML.

Answer (score 1):

When normal behavior of the application is blocked by the rule set, this is called a false positive. The article [Handling False Positives with the OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set](https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorial-8_handling-false-positives-modsecurity-core-rule-set/) may be of help to you. It describes how to identify the rule that blocks valid requests and to disable it using the `SecRuleRemoveById` configuraiton directive.